# Im unable to get these lines running smoothly in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

im trying it add some lines into my pygame window but the second i want to add a second line it messes up and stops responding. I have tried adding a clock but that hasn't seemed to work.

This is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
w = 800
h = 800
dis = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.set_caption("Hangman")

white = (255, 255, 255)
mistakes = 0

while mistakes < 11:
    while mistakes == 1:
        pygame.draw.line(dis, black, [100, 500], [700, 500], 5)
        pygame.display.update()

    while mistakes == 2:
      pygame.draw.line(dis, white, [100, 500], [700, 500], 5)
        pygame.draw.line(dis, white, [100, 500], [100, 100], 5)
        pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            mistakes += 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the inner `while`-loops. The typical PyGame application loop has to:h

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
w = 800
h = 800
dis = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hangman")

run = True
mistakes = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run and mistakes < 11:
    # limit frames per soecond
    clock.tick(100)

    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            mistakes += 1

    # clear display
    dis.fill("black")

    # draw scene
    if mistakes > 0:
        pygame.draw.line(dis, "white", (100, 500), (700, 500), 5)
    if mistakes > 1:
        pygame.draw.line(dis, "white", (100, 500), (100, 100), 5)
    if mistakes > 2:
        pygame.draw.line(dis, "white", (100, 100), (400, 100), 5)
    # [...]
    
    # update display  
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```